# VirtualDub - how to preserve previous video compression rate?

Tags: video

I need to simply split large (~1400mb) file into 100mb video files with the same quality (compression rate). I need it done in short time so in that case VirtualDub will not use any compression operations, but just split video into small ones. What is the right way to do that? Is there alternative free software to do that?

Answer (score 2):

With VirtualDub try this:

- Open the video
- Video => Direct Stream Copy
- Audio => Direct Stream Copy
- File => Save segmented AVI...
- File segment size limit in MB => 100
- click Save